# Looking for a syntax evaluater for expressions constructed for use in SSRS reporting

Tags: sql, visual-studio

My company currently uses the report-building suite in Microsoft's Visual Studio 2010 to construct report templates in .rdlc format based on data drawn from an SQL server. This has been working OK for us, but due to some licencing issues we are having to move to the more basic SQL Report Builder. The main issue with this is that SQL Report Builder doesn't evaluate expression syntax at design time, which causes pain for many of our less techy users. Visual Studio does this in the following way:

[image]

Obviously this basic syntax error is easy to resolve in Report Builder for simple expressions such as the above, but for complex expressions we are starting to struggle with missing commas, brackets, or just general formatting issues. This isn't helped due to the compiling solution we are using alongside Report Builder does not give area-specific error messages if incorrect syntax is found when compiling - just a general message that the report failed to run.

Does anyone know of an online/free/low cost service that will evaluate SSRS expression syntax? Apologies if any of my terminology is wrong, let me know if anything needs clarifying.